# Not showing Media images in Django however Static files work

Tags: python, django, ckeditor, django-media

I am out of my depth and would like to ask you about my challenge with some images that won't load on my project. Images and CSS from the **static** folder get loaded successfully. But my images from the **media** folder are what is not showing up with error

> GET /images/uploads/2021/02/11/pexels-carly-jamieson-1478450.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404

I have already done `python manage.py collectstatic` plenty of times. For media files I use `ckeditor` image uploader. Files get uploaded fine, I can see them in the media folder. The thing is, this used to work before and now it just does not.

settings.py

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
from decouple import config

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
DEBUG = config('DEBUG', default=False, cast=bool)
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost']

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    #my apps
    'blog',
    'ckeditor',
    'ckeditor_uploader',
]

CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = "uploads/"

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'portfolio.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'portfolio/templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'portfolio.wsgi.application'
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True

# Heroku settings
cwd = os.getcwd()
if cwd == '/app' or cwd[:4] == '/tmp':
    import dj_database_url
    DATABASES = {
'default': dj_database_url.config(default='postgres://localhost')
}
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]
MEDIA_URL = '/images/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets/')
```

urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

app_name = "blog"

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('blog.urls', namespace='blog')),
    path('ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls'))
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from portfolio.utils import unique_slug_generator
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
#from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
from ckeditor_uploader.fields import RichTextUploadingField

class BlogPost(models.Model):
    """A blog entry"""
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    intro = models.TextField(blank='True')
    text = RichTextUploadingField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date_added']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

def slug_generator(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if not instance.slug:
        instance.slug = unique_slug_generator(instance)

pre_save.connect(slug_generator, sender=BlogPost)

class Contact(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.EmailField()
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    message = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I've tried different suggestions from SO with no luck. I want to sincerely ask all of you Django masters for your expertise and show me the way to make the images I upload to display. I really appreciate your kindness and generosity!

Comment: Please show template code which tries to show media files. And evaluate BASE_DIR in runtime, check all the settings folders correctness. And I'm not sure why you've added these models since they don't have any media attributes like `ImageField`.

Comment: I have printed my BASE_DIR and it did reflect that the BASE_DIR is the root directory of my project. I appreciate your input sir. I was able to solve this problem already by making sure debug is True. ALso I am displaying it on admin site only for the images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**settings.py:**

```
CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = 'uploads/'
CKEDITOR_IMAGE_BACKEND = "pillow"
CKEDITOR_THUMBNAIL_SIZE = (500, 500)
CKEDITOR_IMAGE_QUALITY = 40
CKEDITOR_BROWSE_SHOW_DIRS = True
CKEDITOR_JQUERY_URL = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js'
```

set image backend as pillow

Comment: sorry sir it did not work but thank you so much as that will stick to my code! My late reply was because I was so frustrated on this problem. I solved it on by setting debut variable to false :( basic mistake. I feel so stupid. I appreciate your code though :)